# dplyr: getting group_by-column even when not selecting it

Tags: r, dplyr

When selecting columns I get one column I haven't selected but it's a group_by column:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(i=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), j=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2), x=runif(8))

df %>% 
  group_by(i,j) %>%
  summarize(s=sum(x)) %>%
  filter(i==1) %>%
  select(s)
```

I get column i even I haven't selected it:

```
  i         s
1 1 0.8355195
2 1 0.9322474
```

Why does this happen (why not column j?) and how can I avoid it? Okay I could filter at the beginning....

Comment: this is a `dplyr` question, not `magrittr`

Comment: You used `group_by()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the grouping variable is carried on by default. Please see [the `dplyr` vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html):

> Grouping affects the verbs as follows: grouped `select()` is the same as ungrouped `select()`, except that grouping variables are always retained.

Note that (each) `summarize` peels off one layer of grouping (in your case, `j`), so after the `summarize`, your data is only grouped by `i` and that is printed in the output. If you don't want that, you can ungroup the data before selecting `s`:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(i,j) %>%
  summarize(s=sum(x)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(i==1) %>%
  select(s)
#Source: local data frame [2 x 1]
#
#         s
#1 1.129867
#2 1.265131
```