# R & dplyr's select not removing columns after various transforms?

Tags: r, dplyr

It looks like select isn't removing un-selected columns from data-set.. quite odd. Here is a simple example :

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

dly <- flights %>% 
  group_by( year, month, day) %>%
  summarise(
    arr_mean = mean(arr_delay, na.rm=TRUE),
    dep_mean = mean(dep_delay, na.rm=TRUE)
  ) %>% mutate(
    dt = as.Date(ISOdate( year, month, day ) )
  ) 

> glimpse( dly, 50 )
Observations: 365
Variables: 6
$ year     (int) 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013...
$ month    (int) 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...
$ day      (int) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1...
$ arr_mean (dbl) 12.6510229, 12.6928879, 5.73...
$ dep_mean (dbl) 11.548926, 13.858824, 10.987...
$ dt       (date) 2013-01-01, 2013-01-02, 201...
```

So... simple.. get a mean by day, and add a R date. (yes, I know there is a time_hour in the data set, but this should still work). Now I want to get rid of the  year, month & day fields (to gather() for ggplot)... but select isn't striping them out :

```
dly %>% select( dt, arr_mean, dep_mean) %>% glimpse(50)
Observations: 365
Variables: 5
$ year     (int) 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013...
$ month    (int) 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...
$ dt       (date) 2013-01-01, 2013-01-02, 201...
$ arr_mean (dbl) 12.6510229, 12.6928879, 5.73...
$ dep_mean (dbl) 11.548926, 13.858824, 10.987...
```

day is gone, but the year and month are still there. why?

even if I romp on them, they are still there :

```
dly$year <- NULL
dly$month <- NULL
dly$day <- NULL

dly %>% glimpse(50)

Observations: 365
Variables: 3
$ arr_mean (dbl) 12.6510229, 12.6928879, 5.73...
$ dep_mean (dbl) 11.548926, 13.858824, 10.987...
$ dt       (date) 2013-01-01, 2013-01-02, 201...
```

Seems like they are gone, but they really arn't :

```
dly %>% select( dep_mean) %>% glimpse(50)
Error: invalid column index : NA for variable: year = year
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not sure what.

if I don't group_by / mutate the data it works fine.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Not really documented that I see (at least not in `?select`), but grouping columns are special. Just `ungroup()` before selecting, deleting, etc.

Comment: Sometimes, R messes up big time when dealing with functions common to *plyr* and *dplyr*.  Have you tried prefixing `dplyr::` to every *dplyr*'s function call, just for debugging purposes?

Comment: Please study the [`dplyr` vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html): (1) "Grouping affects the verbs as follows: grouped `select()` is the same as ungrouped `select()`, except that _grouping variables are always retained_." (2) "When you group by multiple variables, each summary peels off one level of the grouping." ~~> OP: "day is gone, but the year and month are still there."

Comment: Possible duplicates / related Q&A [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039704/dplyr-getting-group-by-column-even-when-not-selecting-it) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969365/error-selecting-a-column-after-grouping-the-dataframe-using-group-by-from-dplyr)

Comment: Nice find on the vignette. Seems like it should be mentioned in at least one of the help pages for `select`, `group_by`, `grouped_df`/`grouped_dt`. Maybe I'll make a pull request...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run `dly%>%head()`, you'll see in the console that `dly` is still grouped :

```
Groups: year, month [1]
```

Insert an `%>% ungroup()%>%` before selecting should "free" `dly`

Comment: That works. Thanks. I didn't understand the vignette issue.